# EWS notification email address on recipient read

Tags: notifications, sendmail, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS to send email from an application.

The emails go out on behalf of a service user and set the `IsReadReceiptRequested` and `IsDeliveryReceiptRequested` properties to true, but I need to set the address where the notifications are to go. The service user mailbox is not monitored.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

I found the right solution for the read notification:

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_ReadReceiptAddrType_W = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x4029, MapiPropertyType.String);
msg.SetExtendedProperty(PR_ReadReceiptAddrType_W, "SMTP");
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_ReadReceiptEmailAddr_W = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x402A, MapiPropertyType.String);
msg.SetExtendedProperty(PR_ReadReceiptEmailAddr_W, "<address>");
```

But I can't find the delivery tags.

And, I don't know how I could use the `Return-Receipt-to` and `disposition-notification-to` with managed EWS.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to set the Reply-To header.